# Import Python Functions and Private Functions with Conflicting Module Names

Tags: python, module, package

Say I have have the following Python package directory structure:

```
package
    sample/
        __init__.py
        a.py
```

Where `sample/a.py` contains a few functions:

```
def _a(x):
    ...
    return some_result

def _b():
    return 7

def a(x):
    """
    Wrapper for `_a()`
    """
    return _a(x)

def c():
    return _b()
```

Usually, to call `a()`, I would do:

```
import sample as smp

smp.a.a(5)
```

But to make it slightly simpler and need less typing (since my module names and function names are really much longer), I could modify the `sample/__init__.py` file with:

```
from .a import a
```

And then, I can now do:

```
import sample as smp

smp.a(5)
```

However, there are times when I need to call some of the other functions like `_b()` or `c()` (i.e., for some unit tests) but I don't want those functions to be (easily) accessible to the user as `smp._b()` or `smp.c()`. So, modifying `sample/__init__.py` with the following is **undesirable**:

```
from .a import a, _b, c
```

Instead, I want the other functions to only be accessible in this way:

```
import sample as smp

smp.a(5)

# The following lines will error out
smp.a._(5)
smp.a._b()
smp.a.c()
```

However, this isn't possible since `smp.a` is already defined as a function rather than a module name. How can I do this without moving the additional functions into a separate file?

Comment: Can you do `from .a import a as new_a`?

Comment: From a logical standpoint, it is important that the `a` function not have its name be changed. But it might be reasonable to change the module name to `py_a`. It's not ideal though...